# Transform that preserve namespace prefixes

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nlog, xdt-transform

I'm trying to insert an NLog custom config section into my Web.config using this XDT section:

```
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" throwExceptions="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" >
    <targets>
        <target xsi:type="File" name="logfile" fileName="H:\testLog.txt" layout="${longdate} ${uppercase:${level}} ${message}" />
    </targets>
    <rules>
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="logfile" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

When I run the XDT transform, my Web.Debug.config contains:

```
<nlog throwExceptions="true" xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd">
    <targets>
        <target d4p1:type="File" name="logfile" fileName="H:\testLog.txt" layout="${longdate} ${uppercase:${level}} ${message}" xmlns:d4p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />
    </targets>
    <rules>
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="logfile" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

Typically, a namespace prefix is arbitrary, so transforming xsi to d4p1 would cause no issues.

However, I get a runtime exception in my application from NLog when I use `d4p1`. Manually changing the instances of `d4p1` to `xsi` fixes the issue, but it subverts the utility of config transformation for me if the user needs to manually alter the file afterward.

Is there a way to preserve namespace prefixes using XDT?

Comment: Sorry, not yet. This XDT behavior is aggravating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We had exactly the same issue. I'm not sure why it suddenly started happening with a particular project, but the solution for us was to add the xsi namespace to the top level of the original configuration file (ie the base file the transformations work on). So...

```
<configuration>
```

... would become...

```
<configuration xmlns:xsi="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd">
```

This did the trick.

An alternative approach that also worked was to apply the transforms on child elements of the nlog element.

Hope that helps someone.

Comment: That doesn't seem right. The `xsi` namespace should be `"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"`.

Comment: @StevenLiekens Comment Worked for me

Answer (score 2):

I started to see this problem when I moved my xdt:Transform attribute from the target and rule tags to nlog. Moving them back to the original tags like this solved it:

```
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" throwExceptions="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <targets xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
    <target xsi:type="File" name="logfile" fileName="H:\testLog.txt" layout="${longdate} ${uppercase:${level}} ${message}" />
  </targets>
  <rules xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="logfile" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Comment: THANK YOU!  I've been having this problem and every solution doesn't explain with an example how to get it working.  It's working!